# How do I create a CGRect from a CGPoint and CGSize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics, cgpoint, cgrectmake

I need to create a frame for a `UIImageView` from a varying collection of `CGSize` and `CGPoint`, both values will always be different depending on user's choices. So how can I make a `CGRect` form a `CGPoint` and a `CGSize`? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Two different options for Objective-C:

```
CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, aSize.width, aSize.height);

CGRect aRect = { aPoint, aSize };
```

Swift 3:

```
let aRect = CGRect(origin: aPoint, size: aSize)
```

Comment: What kind of operator are you using here in your second example?

Comment: Just the normal assignment operator.

Comment: I mean the curly brackets. Is this some sort of macro. I know about the native `NSDictionary @{}` and `NSArray @[]` operator but this one looks new to me.

Comment: It's a compound literal.  They are part of C, standardised in C99.

Comment: In XCODE 5 it raises: expected expression. This is correct syntax: (CGRect){aPoint, aSize}

Comment: @Pion: No it doesn't.  That code works fine and doesn't produce any warnings in the latest version of Xcode.  I'm assuming you're using different code, doing something other than initialising a local variable.  You need the cast if you want to do something like pass a compound literal as a method argument, but just for initialising a local variable, you don't need the cast.

Comment: I'm passing as argument so thats the answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

Building on the most excellent answer from @Jim, one can also construct a CGPoint and a CGSize using this method. So these are also valid ways to make a CGRect:

```
CGRect aRect = { {aPoint.x, aPoint.y}, aSize };
CGrect aRect = { aPoint, {aSize.width, aSize.height} };
CGRect aRect = { {aPoint.x, aPoint.y}, {aSize.width, aSize.height} };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CGRectMake(yourPoint.x, yourPoint.y, yourSize.width, yourSize.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some sugar syntax. For example:

This is something like construction block you can use for more readable code:

```
CGRect rect = ({
   CGRect customCreationRect

   //make some calculations for each dimention
   customCreationRect.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(yourFrame);
   customCreationRect.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(someOtherFrame);

   customCreationRect.size.width = CGRectGetHeight(yetAnotherFrame);
   customCreationRect.size.height = 400;

   //By just me some variable in the end this line will
   //be assigned to the rect va
   customCreationRect;
)}
```