# CGRect Swift code equivalence in objective c

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone tell me what is going to be equivalence of this swift code in objective c

```
let someView = SomeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height:self.view.bounds.size.height ))
self.view.addSubview(SomeView)
```

Where SomeView is a UIView.

I went through Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect

and

this question on stack overflow: [How do I create a CGRect from a CGPoint and CGSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063650/how-do-i-create-a-cgrect-from-a-cgpoint-and-cgsize)

but couldn't able to comprehend how can I do the same in Obj-c

Comment: It's something like `CGRectMake`

Comment: Yeah here you go: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455245-cgrectmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the `CGRectMake` function is the preferred way.  Given a `point` that is `CGPoint` and a `size` that is `CGSize`:

```objectivec
CGRect r = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, size.width, size.height);
```

However `CGRect` is just a C `struct` that is defined to be this:

```objectivec
struct CGRect {
    CGPoint origin;
    CGSize size;
};
```

so you can also initialize it just like you would any `struct` in standard C.

```objectivec
CGRect r = { point, size };
```

Also since C is a lot less picky about uninitialized variables than Swift you can also do this, though it is less preferred even in C:

```objectivec
CGRect r;
r.origin = point;
r.size = size;
```

So to translate this Swift code,

```swift
let someView = SomeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height:self.view.bounds.size.height ))
self.view.addSubview(SomeView)
```

into Objective-C, first we have to assume `SomeView` is a type accessible in Objective-C (for example, `NSView` or `UIView`, but not SwiftUI's `View`).  You also have to keep in mind that Objective-C separates allocation and initialization, creating something of an idiom that looks like `[[ClassName alloc] init:...];`.

Additionally you have to take into account something that Swift underwent early on called the "Grand Renaming".  A lot of methods and initializers from AppKit/UIKit were renamed in Swift to be more "Swifty", but they retain their original names in Objective-C.  For that reason when you look things up in Apple docs in Swift to find how to call it in Objective-C, it's useful to go to the method/initializer detail in Swift, because you're familiar with it, and then switch to Obj-C to see it's Obj-C name.

If you do that with `NSView`'s `init(frame:)` you find that in Obj-C it's `initWithFrame:`.

```objectivec
SomeView* someView = [[SomeView alloc] initWithFrame: { {0, 0}, bounds.size }];
[self addSubview: someView];
```

or

```objectivec
SomeView* someView = [[SomeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)];
[self addSubview: someView];
```

Comment: In swift, they have a UI view to which they are passing this a parameter or something like that? `SomeView(frame: CGRect(x`. 
How would this work in obj-C. 
Also, thanks for answering :)

Comment: I'll update my answer to include that view creation example.

Comment: Updated, also corrected the name of the function to make the rect.  It's `CGRectMake`, not `CGMakeRect`